Cannot access vite (vue3) server on network even after setting 'host' property
I have an application with a python Flask backend and a Vite Vue3 frontend. I am trying to make the Vite frontend accessible over the network.
I have set server.host to 0.0.0.0 in vite.config.js
But the website is still inaccesible.
I even went into package.json and modified the dev script to vite --host 0.0.0.0.
When I run the application with npm run dev, I see my public IP address listed but I still cannot access the application on the network.
This is not an issue with the Flask server. I even changed the flask port to 5173 (the default Vite port that my Vue3 app was using) and with the following line of python code I can access the Flask application over the network without any issues.
app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=5173)

A few additional notes:

The server is running on Windows 10 and the other device is an Android phone running Chrome.
Both devices are on the same WiFi network with IP addresses of the form 192.168.x.x
I can access the website using this address (192.168.x.x) from the machine itself.
Unfortunately, there is no screenshot to share since it's just stuck loading for several seconds before timing out.


Is it an IP like 192.168.x.x? Check if you maybe have some specific router settings or maybe some /etc/hosts specific config. Try with your phone connected to the wifi too. Does it work if you try to access the website from the machine itself? How did you create the project? Mind sharing a screenshot of the error?

I have added additional details to the question which should answer your questions.

If you can access it, then everything works fine nah? Not sure to understand the problem here.

To clarify, I CANNOT access a VITE/VUE3/NPM application over the network BUT I CAN ACCESS a PYTHON FLASK application over the network running on the same port.

Well, this seems to be fixed for me in the latest version of Vue/Vite ...
